# Ubuntu 15.04 touchpad not recognized

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad

I have an Acer travelmate (P2).
The cursor worked fine on windows seven.

I first tried to work with a live -stick with ubuntu 14.04, then 15.04.

Both times, I do not see any cursor. 
I have already found out that the touchpad for some reason is not recognized (the keyboard works fine).

Problem is, all solutions I can find involve installing something, and how can I possibly use WLAN (choose a specific connection, password and so on) without a cursor?

Is there any solution without using WLAN?

I am willing do delete my stick and create a different one if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

´Solved it, after a lot of searching.

Apparently it works when I press CTRL + Fn + F7 during the booting process.

No Idea why actually, but it works.